# scan dates from JSON and print specific content on the basis of date

Tags: php, html, json, date

I have a php code as shown below:

**Php Code:**

```
<?php
    the_title('<h1 class="position">', '</h1>');
    echo '<span class="data">' .date('yy-m-d').  '</span>'; // Line B
    echo '<span class="part">Sitting Day</span>';  // Line C
?>
```

The above php code (Line B and Line C) prints the following:
I am using **Sitting Day** at Line C (just for fun) but it should print what is inside the JSON below:

**JSON:**

```
{
    "position_day": ["2020-01-15", "2020-01-16", "2020-01-17"],
    "proc_no": ["no", "yes", "no"]
}
```

**Edit 1:** *I am not controlling the JSON. The values inside the JSON are passed via UI*.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above (specially at Line B and Line C) so that ***Line B*** **looks/match/scan** for a date inside the **JSON** above and **print content at *Line C*** 
on the basis of date in the **JSON**.

**Case 1:**
If today's date is **2020-01-15** at Line B and its **no** for the corresponding date in the JSON, then it should say **Not a Sitting Day** at Line C.

**Case 2:**
If today's date is **2020-01-16** at Line B and its **yes** for the corresponding date in the JSON, then it should say **Sitting Day** at Line C.

**Case 3:** 
If today's date is **2020-01-22** at Line B and nothing is present in the JSON for that particular date, then it should say display blank/nothing at Line C.

Comment: Didn't you post this earlier?

Comment: Yes, I posted that earlier. I thought I didn't post my question properly so I thought to re-post it.

Comment: Are you the person who controls what the JSON looks like? If so, just change it to something like `house_sitting_dates: [{ "date":"2020-01-15", "did_sit": false}, {"date":"2020-01-16", "did_sit": true}]`. Otherwise, when you loop through one of them, just keep a reference to the index and spit out the same indexed value from the other array.

Comment: I am not controlling the JSON. Values inside the JSON go through UI.

Comment: Some relation need to be made between Line B/Line C and JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description here is the change:

```
<?php
if (file_exists('feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json')) {
    $data_house = json_decode(file_get_contents('feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json'));
}

// $strdate = strtotime('2020-01-17');
// $date = date("Y-m-d", $strdate);

$date = date("Y-m-d");
$answer_prefix = "Not a ";

$sitting_day_str = "Sitting Day";
?>
<span class="current-date"><?php echo $date ?></span>
<?php foreach( $data_house->house_sitting_date as $key=>$val) {
  if($date === $val && $data_house->house_sitting_date_yes_no[$key] === "yes") {
    $answer_prefix = "";
    break;
  }
}
?>
<?php if(in_array($date, $data_house->house_sitting_date)) {?>
  <span class="current-date-answer"><?php echo $answer_prefix . $sitting_day_str ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Note: this can be cleaner by having it in a function, but I will leave to you since you provided little information about what you are using as framework/CMS.

Comment: I have added one more case. It seems to be working` for **Case 1** and **Case 2** but for **Case 3** it is printing **Not a Sitting Day**. It should display blank for **Case 3**

Comment: Will check it now!

Comment: Hi Ma'moun, I hope all is well. I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532447/array-filter-doesnt-seems-to-work-for-words-having-apostrophe-and-dash). I am wondering if you can have a look.

Comment: Thank you. Its related to unicode and array_filter.

Answer (score 0):

This works by keeping track of the index we are looping through (`$i`) and using it for both arrays. The only problem here would be if one of those arrays were a different size than the other, in which case you'll run into errors.

The code is not guaranteed to run -- I don't have access to a PHP environment right now -- but I hope you can do whatever minor debugging would be necessary to get a working solution.

```
<?php
$data_house = json_decode(file_get_contents('feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json'));

for($i = 0; $i < count($data_house['house_sitting_date']; $i++) {
?>
  <span class="current-date"> <?php echo date('yy-m-d', $data_house['house_sitting_data'][$i]).</span>
  <span class="current-date-answer"><?php $data_house['house_sitting_date_yes_no'][$i] == 'yes' ? 'Sitting Day' : 'Not a Sitting Day' ?></span>
<?php
}
?>
```