# array_filter doesn't seems to work for words having apostrophe and dash

Tags: php, arrays, unicode, utf-8, array-filter

I have a **php code** as shown below:

```
$variable = \CTIME\DataPoint\get_message();  // Line A
echo '<pre>'; print_r($variable); echo '</pre>';  // Line B
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($variable); echo '</pre>';  // Line C
print_r(array_filter($variable, function ($i) { return $i->top_portion == 'Hello – World'; }));  // Line D
```

**Line B** prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [language] => en
            [client_id] => 12345
            [top_portion] => Hello World
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [language] => en
            [client_id] => 56789
            [top_portion] => Hello – World
        )

)
```

**Line C** prints:

```
array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'language' => 'en',
     'client_id' => 12345,
     'top_portion' => 'Hello World',
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'language' => 'en',
     'client_id' => 56789,
     'top_portion' => 'Hello – World',
  ),
)
```

**Line D** prints:

```
Array 
(
)
```

**Problem Statement:**

I'm wondering what PHP code I need to add so that it prints only the object which has **[top_portion] => Hello – World**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [language] => en
            [client_id] => 56789
            [top_portion] => Hello – World
        )
)
```

This is what **I have tried**:

```
print_r(array_filter($variable, function ($i) { return $i->top_portion == 'Hello – World'; }));
```

It prints;

```
Array
(
)
```

Comment: Works fine for me: https://3v4l.org/FOjXu

Comment: It works fine..

Comment: Its not working for me still. Not sure what is the reason.

Comment: @flash can you post the output of `var_export($scheduled_streams);` instead of the print_r() so we can copy&paste the result to fiddle around with?

Comment: and P.S.: Do you assign the filtered array or just expect the passed array to be filtered by reference (talking about return value of `array_filter()` here)?

Comment: @ArSeN Updated my question

Comment: @flash In your text, the `’` is not a "normal" single-quote mark (`'`).  It's actually a Unicode character (`\u2019`) https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm  The other character, the `–` is also not a "normal" hyphen/dash.  It's an em-dash (`\u2013`) https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm

Comment: @flash thanks, still appears to work. Can you answer my question about the return value? i.e. when you say "it prints" - where is the code that actually prints? And is the return value assigned?

Comment: Maybe your PHP version doesn't support utf8/multi-byte strings properly?  What version of PHP are you running?  What does `echo mb_get_info('internal_encoding');` output?

Comment: Current version is PHP 7.3.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Comment: @ArSeN Good catch on the `array_filter` line.  @flash, `array_filter` returns a new array, it doesn't modify the original array.

Comment: Where is the code that actually prints ? Answer: LineA, Line B and Line C are in the php file. o/ps are printed on the web page.

Comment: echo mb_get_info('internal_encoding'); prints **UTF-8**

Comment: @flash where is the line that prints the "blank" array you are seeing?  Are you setting a variable to `array_filter(...)` since it returns a new array?

Comment: @RocketHazmat updated my code. Let me know if its make sense.

Comment: @flash Not sure what the issue is... it seems to work fine for me https://3v4l.org/jRS48

Comment: @RocketHazmat Not sure what is happening.

Comment: Weird, any chance you can gist (or something) a phpinfo() output? Also: If you copy&paste the exact code (including the hardcoded data array) from the 3v4ls that have been pasted here, does it work on your machine? or still no?

Comment: phpinfo() shows big o/p. Is there any specific thing you want to know ?

Comment: @ArSeN It is working when I copy-paste the code from 3v4ls. Weird.

Comment: @flash No specific idea about the PHPinfo I would just have scrolled it through and see whats what. My guess is that `\CTIME\LiveStreams\get_live_today_streams()` outputs something else than Line B output is supposed to do - not saying you fail to copy it, just that maybe it gets lost in the "translation" to stackoverflow somewhere in between

Comment: Have you tried constructing your comparison string (in the filtering callback) by inserting the unicode characters that Rocket suggested? Something along the lines of `"Hello \u{2013} Aujourd\u{2019}hui"`. Although I suspect the u2019 could alternatively be [u02BC](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02bc/index.htm), so I'd try that too. Is that filtering anything?

Comment: @El_Vanja something like this ? `array_filter($scheduled_streams, function ($i) { return $i->program_title == "Hello \u{2013} Aujourd\u{2019}hui"; });`

Comment: Yeah, like that. Any luck with that or the other (u02BC) variant?

Comment: No luck with that. I didn't try with **(u02BC)** variant.

Comment: For **(u02BC)** variant, it should be like this `array_filter($scheduled_streams, function ($i) { return $i->program_title == "Hello \u{2013} Aujourd\u{02BC}hui"; });` **?**

Comment: Exactly. You just switch the u-code inside the curly brackets.

Comment: Still didn't work.

Comment: Are you allowed to share the code that actually gets the streams? I don't see how we'll solve it without the actual contents that are causing the problem.

Comment: Could you possibly grab the output from "Line C" again and put it into a github gist? My guess is still that some invisible characters (or something) get lost when posting here (not trying to encourage posting outside of SO, just to get a grip on this)

Comment: I wonder if the string you're getting is actually `UTF-16` encoded rather than `UTF-8`. What happens if you try `print_r(array_filter($a, function ($i) { return $i->program_title == mb_convert_encoding('Hello – Aujourd’hui', 'UTF-16'); }));`?

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems good.
My guess is that this is a charset issue: the "right single quotation mark" (’) is a unicode char and is not part of ASCII charset.

If the string from the source data and the string in your PHP script use a distinct charset, they might be different (not the same sequence of bytes).

For instance, if you're using UTF-8: check that the data you're fetching with `get_live_today_streams()` is UTF-8 encoded, and make sure that your `.php` file is UTF-8 encoded as well.

(Have a look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256049/how-do-i-convert-an-ansi-encoded-file-to-utf-8-with-notepad) to see how to convert a ANSI file to UTF-8 using notepad++)

Answer (score 2):

You have an encoding mismatch, and I will wager that it's between UTF-8 and MS cp1252.

cp1252 is a single-byte encoding that Microsoft uses, and is frequently confused with ISO8859-1. While many of the codepoints map to the same glyphs in both, there are some notable differences like `’` that give it away as it only occurs in cp1252.

If you look at the byte values of strings you'll see:

- cp1252: `\x92`
- UTF-8: `\xE2\x80\x99`

Which is why you're having trouble matching.

You're going to want to make this post your new religion: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Without re-hashing that gospel truth, my over-arching recommendations on dealing with character encodings are:

1. Never *assume* a character encoding, always set it explicitly.
2. Never attempt to *detect* a character encoding, as it is virtually impossible to do with any level of accuracy.
3. ***Never*** use `utf8_encode()` or `utf8_decode()`.

   - They will only ever convert between ISO8859-1 and UTF-8.
   - They do not make any attempt to check if the input is the encoding they expect. [see point 2]
   - Even when they encounter an detectably *invalid* byte sequence they do not make any attempt to care and will simple introduce trash into the output.
4. ***Always*** use functions like [`mb_convert_encoding()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) or [`iconv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php), and ***always*** specify both the input and output encodings. [see point 1]

Answer (score 0):

If your string always contains Hello and Aujourd hui, use this regex workaround - notice the `u` flag that makes it multibyte compatible to match the dash and quote characters with a dot.

https://3v4l.org/Xe0Rg